# What condition can be used in a policy to enforce an S3 bucket requires server-side-encryption?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

An explicit deny rule would be used to prevent the creation of S3 buckets that did not include a server-side-encryption option (either AES or KMS).  An explicit denial is the preferred outcome to prevent accidental creation.

I can locate the option specified in the creation through the console, yet not the cli `create-bucket` command.

I understand that the `put-bucket-encryption` command can be used as a follow-on as an administrative control and a detective/corrective control can be implemented through Lambda or other means, but that bypasses the active control requirement.

The expected result would be to apply a policy that explicitly denies create, modify, read-contents, et al regarding a bucket without the accompanying attribute `SSEAlgorithm` or functional equivalent is absent or not matched.

Comment: If you aren't able to proactively require SSE when creating a bucket then you'll need to reactively apply it. I suspect the AWS console is simply making these two operations appear to be one operation.

Comment: @jarmod I understand that to be the case, please see the text of the original post...  
"I understand that the put-bucket-encryption command can be used  
 as a follow-on as an administrative control and a detective/corrective control  
 can be implemented through Lambda or other means, but that bypasses the  
 active control requirement."

Comment: @jarmod Thank you but again you are missing the requirement to have an active control that prevents the creation of a bucket that doesn't have default SSE enabled on it as the create-bucket action is called.

Comment: AWS Config offers a managed rule, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-server-side-encryption-enabled.html

Comment: Can you deny access for creating buckets to all users and only have a service that will create a bucket according to preferred settings (when needed spread into different calls) ?

Comment: @Walter "Deny access to all except to a specific service which sequences the creation to assure a valid `put-bucket-encryption` is immediately supplied."  
  
It's not exactly in accordance with the compliance as written, but it is most certainly the tightest mitigation as an active control.  We would have to also have other 'helper' functions to avoid modifying the bucket to alter the configuration as a subversion, but I think this would satisfy my issue as a solid mitigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first gave this as a comment, OP thinks it is a reasonable mitigation:

Deny access for creating buckets to all users using the AWS console.
Write a special service that will create a bucket according to preferred settings (when needed spread into different calls).
Another side effect is that you can streamline additional requirements, like a check on the bucket name (e.g. company_project_module_xxx) and documentation (add creator/cration time/comment into documentation bucket).

Comment: A lot of S3 buckets are created via an installation process of a third party service. So this solution would not work in this scenario and in many cases this is the use case hardest to manage because if people are creating them manually we can at least tell them to do X,Y and Z - even if they don't always listen. So any solution needs to be incorporated into the API.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
      "Sid": "DenyNoEncryption",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test_bucket/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
        }
      }
    }
```

This is how a policy could look to deny adding objects to an s3 bucket without sse.

If you need to stop creating s3 buckets without sse. Change the s3 action to `"s3:CreateBucket"` I believe this should work for you. And then change your resource to be `*`

```
{
      "Sid": "DenyNoEncryption",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "s3:CreateBucket",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your 2nd policy is presumably an attempt at an S3 bucket policy (because it has a Principal). You won't be able to configure that on a bucket until the bucket exists.